# Creating an Alternate Google Earth--Is This Possible?

Tags: earth-like, geography, worldbuilding-process, geology

This question concerns the following images I've made for an alternate Earth:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Marked in brown are mountains.  Marked in red or orange are plateaus or cracks from ancient lava flows.  Marked in black are lands that don't physically exist in this world.

The best way to create these maps realistically is via Google Maps.  But is it possible?  Is there a program on Google Earths where I can alter the geography, geology and topography of the Earth to my whim?

Comment: The answer is likely to be "no" for a number of reasons, but a more specific answer somewhat depends on what you want to use the altered maps for. First of all, you can't publish what you make (unless you're willing to pay obscene licensing fees). More relevant, what resolution do you need? Reading postage stamps on the sidewalk, or the "world" level you're showing above? That will drive what tools you need.

Comment: It's for an alternate history project that I've been working on.

Comment: That... doesn't answer either of my questions. Are you planning to publish your alternate maps, or are they for personal use only? And, more importantly, what resolution do you need?

Comment: Both.  Whichever resolution Google allows.

Comment: Understand, Google doesn't allow any of this. Google Maps/Earth uses satellite data to generate maps; no one's handcrafted anything, it's all computer algorithms acting on aerial/satellite photos. This means there's no tooling to edit terrain. Also, you're talking about manually editing millions of square miles of terrain to postage-stamp detail, which will take longer than your lifetime. If you could be more specific with what you were going to _use_ the maps for, I could possibly be more helpful.

Comment: It's for an alternate history project that I've been working on.

Comment: Here's the link for permissions using google maps: https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html As you'll see, it's quite limited as to what you are allowed to do.

Comment: Have you tried screenshotting the relevant areas on Google maps/earth, and using image editing software to create the required results?

Comment: I believe it is possible to use softwares to create a Google map like effect were you can zoom on the map. For that you need several maps of the same areas at different scales tough.

Comment: @Vincent  You know any links for this?

Comment: The only soft I remember is not being sold anymore but I think someone might know the answer here https://www.cartographersguild.com/forum.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohnWDailey;  In a word, No.  as noted in comments above, there are software copyright and licensing restrictions that would hamper even the best funded effort.  I have tried to use GoogleEarth API calls in some past B.I. work I've done, they just aren't likely to share, and - they already have obscene amounts of money - you can't buy them.
  To that point, *if you are willing to really do some coding* you can produce GIS data, based on a fictional world. GIS mapping is already underway on Mars, and we haven't been there yet. Given a sufficiently granular graphical model, you can create the same type mapping data that Google uses.  Please see the [DeepTime Maps at NAU](https://deeptimemaps.com/) for a sense of otherworld mapping.  Please also see the GIS /ESRI tools ( this is not an endorsement, merely an idea) at [ARCGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis)
for a view of software that translates data into interactive maps.
  I hope this helps...Hate to see a good question go unanswered.